# Как внести изменение сразу в 100+ html файлов?

Tags: html

Есть сайт в котором много файлов с практически однотипным содержанием.расширение в всех .html
Как возможно внести массовое изменение сразу на все файлы, а не редактировать их в ручную по одному?

Изменить нужно чисто контент, (фото,текст, ссылки, где нужно подправить) Все это делал в ручную очень много времени уходит на редактирование каждого файла.

Comment: Здравствуйте!
Не могли бы Вы конкретизировать вопрос? Какие изменения? Что конкретно нужно поменять? Что Вы уже сделали? Что конкретно не работает?

Comment: [man sed](http://emulek.github.io/sed/ch03.html)

Comment: Не по теме вопроса: если это у вас какой-то статический сайт, то лучше будет взять какой-нибудь генератор статических сайтов с каким-нибудь шаблонизатором, который позволит вынести повторяющиеся фрагменты в отдельные файлы, не копируя их по 100+ раз

Comment: @ВикторМихевич Привет, если знаете язык php, то можете маленький скрипт написать что вазмет файлы и поищит в них тексты по таким критериям каким захотите, потом замените и схроните.

Comment: `phpstorm` вам в помошь

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию найти/заменить в файлах (присутствует в большинстве текстовых редаторов). Рекомендую Notepad++. 
Если изменения однотипны а текстовые блоки могут быть описаны шаблоном, то поможет поиск и замена [с использованием регулярного выражения](http://myhelps.ru/regulyarnyie-vyirazheniya-notepad-s-primerami/).

Answer (score 0):

Скачиваешь все файлы, `notepad++` -> `ctrl+f` -> поиск в папке и выбираешь `найти и заменить`